# Google Charts Pie not complete

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-visualization

I'm using **GoogleCharts** API to display a pie with my gender repartition but I have a little problem, my pie is uncomplete like in the following picture. 
[image]

I generate it with this JSON array :

```
{"cols":[{"id":"","label":"Topping","pattern":"","type":"string"},{"id":"","label":"Slices","pattern":"","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"Homme","f":null},{"v":"2","f":null}]},{"c":[{"v":"Femme","f":null},{"v":"1","f":null}]}]}
```

And this is my Javascript code

```
function drawSexChart() {
      var jsonData = $.ajax({
          url: "http://localhost/studentlink/web/js/ajax.php?sexChart",
          dataType: "json",
          async: false
          }).responseText;
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
      console.log(jsonData);
      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chartUsersBySex'));
      chart.draw(data, null);
  }
```

I haven't any idea why my pie is uncomplete.

If someone can help me ?

Thank you in advance

Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I just find why my pie is uncomplete, I post my solution to help people which have the same problem in future.

Actually, to generate my JSON String, I using the `json_encode` PHP function inside a PHP object which contain all informations about the chart.

But actually, I'm using this function like this :

```
return json_encode($this);
```

**Result**

```
{"cols":[{"id":"","label":"Topping","pattern":"","type":"string"},{"id":"","label":"Slices","pattern":"","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"Homme","f":null},{"v":"2","f":null}]},{"c":[{"v":"Femme","f":null},{"v":"1","f":null}]}]}
```

In this result we can see that the numbers represent my values are between `"`.

But now, if I generate my JSON  String like this :

```
return json_encode($this,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

**Result**

```
{"cols":[{"id":"","label":"Topping","pattern":"","type":"string"},{"id":"","label":"Slices","pattern":"","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"Homme","f":null},{"v":3,"f":null}]},{"c":[{"v":"Femme","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]}]}
```

The `"` characters around my number diseapeared and I have my full pie !

Answer (score 0):

It's because your values are strings and not integers.

[See here](https://jsfiddle.net/zx67qmoe/5/)

So what you need to do is either

1) change the data that is returned from the server so that the row data reflects this

```
"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"Homme","f":null},{"v":2,"f":null}]},{"c":[{"v":"Femme","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]
```

2) Change the data before you use it with the chart app. Example:

```
var rowData = jsonData.rows;
for (var i = 0, l = rowData.length; i < l; i++) {
  rowData[i].c[1].v = +rowData[i].c[1].v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the quotes ("") off the values.

```
{"cols":[{"id":"","label":"Topping","pattern":"","type":"string"},{"id":"","label":"Slices","pattern":"","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"Homme","f":null},{"v":2,"f":null}]},{"c":[{"v":"Femme","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]}]}
```